# Error when trying to install Pillow (python)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
$ pip install Pillow
Error: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm doing this in the command prompt on windows.

Comment: install it https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows

Comment: This means you don't have pip installed. Instructions for installing pip can be found [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

Comment: Did you try `pip3`?

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation for installing pip can be found [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

In short, you can download `get-pip.py` from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) (right-click the link and then choose `Save link as...`). Then you can navigate in the command prompt to the directory you downloaded `get-pip.py` to.

Once you've done that, you can install pip for just your user with

```
python get-pip.py --user
```

If you want to install pip system-wide, you need to use an Administrator command prompt, and run

```
python get-pip.py
```

Then you can install [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) with

```
python -m pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pip, to be able to download packages.

## Installing pip

[Pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) is the package installer for Python and is required to install Python Packages.

1. If you are using [Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html) onwards, then pip should come pre-installed.
2. If you are using a version of Python 3 older than Python 3.4, then the official pip install instructions can be found [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip)

- Note: you can find out what version of Python you are running by typing `python --version` in the terminal
- To check if pip is installed, run `pip help` in the terminal.

## Installing the pillow package

Once you have pip installed, you can now install the pillow package. This is as simple as typing `pip install pillow` into your terminal.

Once you've done this, you will successfully have the pillow package installed for Python.

Answer (score 0):

First run:

```
python
```

if it says that it can't recognize the command, it means you haven't installed python properly on your system. Install it using [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/set-up-python-windows10/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Set%20Up%20Python%20on%20Windows%2010,these%20need%20to%20be%20created.%20More%20items...%20) guide

If python is installed, run this to install pip:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Finally, try installing pillow again. It will probably work now.